# How to get the TimeZone for metazones by using FindSystemTimeZoneById?

Tags: c#, windows, datetime, timezone, registry

I was given the TzID (Olson tzid format Exp: "Europe/Copenhagen"). After that, i tried to do the timezone conversion for certain DateTime from that timezone (different with server local time zone) to UTC by using c# **TimeZonInfo** class.

I was wondering why **window's timezone id** only have about 100 whereas the **timezone id for Olson** tz database have about 405 tz id. Lets say for time zone "Europe/Copenhagen", i have no idea how to use the **FindSystemTimeZonebyID** to get the time zone info for this time zone (It was listed in metazones in the [Olson ID to windows ID convertion table](http://unicode.org/repos/cldr-tmp/trunk/diff/supplemental/zone_tzid.html)). Anyone experienced in this? Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.findsystemtimezonebyid.aspx):

> `FindSystemTimeZoneById` tries to match id to the subkey names of the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones` branch of the registry under Windows XP and Windows Vista. This branch does not necessarily contain a comprehensive list of time zone identifiers.

Based on the table you link to, you want to pass in the string `Europe_Central`, since it is the Windows version of the Olson "Europe/Copenhagen". (Note that according to the MSDN docs, it is not case sensitive.) If that doesn't work, you should check your registry to ensure the `Europe_Central` entry exists.

For more on the Olson tz database  and how it defines timezones, see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database).

---

Update 1:

My registry (Vista) has it listed as `Central Europe Standard Time`, which is the string I'd need to pass in as the parameter, do you have a similar entry?

If that entry isn't in your Registry, you can [create it yourself](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb309898.aspx) using info from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_European_Time), though it looks like you'd have to construct the rules for summer time (see the link).

You could also try using a [`DateTimeOffset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351980.aspx) with a `DateTime` holding the local server time and passing in a `TimeSpan` of +1 hour (CET).

Depending on what you're trying to do, you can also just subtract one hour from the CET time to get UTC. (Though that won't work once [Central Europe Summer Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_European_Time) takes effect; then you'll need to subtract two hours.)

Comment: Thanks a lots for your reply. I checked the registry with the path  'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones' and found that the timezone registry for 'Europe_Central' is not there even after the update for the timezone registry (Downloaded from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/979306). May i know how to add in the timezone registry for those which are not there? If add in the registry manually, it seems to be too many of them. Thanks.

Comment: @darrell: I've added some other options for you to create a simpler time object in C#. I don't know how the registry is structured, and hesitate to suggest editing it. Maybe someone else will know... Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks, i think create time zone class by using TimeZoneInfo.CreateCustomTimeZone Method will far more better and safer than setting time zone by editing registry.